# How does one approach proving facts about non-primitive recursive functions in coq?

Tags: recursion, coq

I'm trying to prove these two addition functions are extensionally the same, however I can't even prove the simplest lemma for the second one.  How does one do this proof over the non-primitive recursive addition function?

```
Fixpoint myadd1 (m n : nat) : nat :=
  match m, n with
    | 0, n => n
    | (S m), n => S (myadd1 m n)
                    end.

Fixpoint myadd2 (m n : nat) : nat :=
  match m, n with
    | 0, n => n
    | (S m), n => myadd2 m (S n)
                    end.

Lemma succlem1 : forall (m n : nat),
  (myadd1 m 0) = m.
Proof.
  intros. induction m.
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - simpl. rewrite IHm.
    reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma succlem12 : forall (m n : nat),
  (myadd2 m 0) = m.
Proof.
  intros. induction m.
  - reflexivity.
  - simpl.
Abort.
```

Edit:

This is what I was trying to prove, and why I was led to this lemma.

```
Lemma succlem : forall (m n : nat),
  S (myadd2 m 0) = myadd2 m 1.
Proof.
  intros. induction m.
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - simpl. rewrite <- IHm.
    simpl.


Theorem succHomo : forall (m n : nat),
  S (myadd2 m n) = myadd2 m (S n).
Proof.
  intros.
  induction n.
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - simpl.
    inversion IHm.

Theorem equivadds : forall (m n : nat),
    myadd1 m n = myadd2 m n.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction m.
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - intros.
    simpl.
    rewrite IHm.
    symmetry.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have an accumulator, you most always want to generalize your induction hypothesis. So, in this case you could first prove that `myadd2` is equivalent to `myadd1`:

```
Lemma myadd1Sr m n :
  myadd1 m (S n) = S (myadd1 m n).
Proof.
now induction m as [|m IHm]; trivial; simpl; rewrite IHm.
Qed.

Lemma myadd2_equiv_myadd1 : forall m n : nat,
  myadd2 m n = myadd1 m n.
Proof.
intros m.  (* important: don't introduce `n` yet -- this will make your IH less general than needed *)
induction m as [| m IHm]; trivial; intros n; simpl.
now rewrite IHm, myadd1Sr.
Qed.
```

Then the rest can be done by simple rewriting:

```
Lemma succlem12 : forall m : nat,
  myadd2 m 0 = m.
Proof.
now intros m; rewrite myadd2_equiv_myadd1, succlem1.
Qed.
```

Comment: I had intended to use the lemma in the proof of the above equation.  I had already gotten as far as you indeed have (with the generalized hypothesis), so please can you suggest how I do the exercise? Or, rather, just give the answer to the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If you show that `myadd1` commutes, it becomes easy to prove that they are equal:

```
Lemma myadd1_comm: forall a b, myadd1 a b = myadd1 b a.
  now induction a; intros; auto; simpl; rewrite IHa.
Qed.       

Lemma myadd2_equiv_myadd1: forall m n, myadd1 m n = myadd2 m n.
  now induction m; intros; auto; simpl; rewrite <- IHm, !(myadd1_comm m).
Qed.
```

Comment: `myadd1_comm` implicitly relies on the standard `plus_n_Sm` lemma (because `myadd1` and `Nat.add` are convertible), so technically you still need to prove one more lemma :)

Comment: @AntonTrunov oops! :)